# How to get picture from flicker to android app?

Tags: java, android, flicker

I have problem with flicker images.how to get all images in flicker to my android app via api through or any other please help me.i am make a simple app in flicker to android please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/

And for Android you can use http://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/

But I guess you could find easily this information alone.